# Realm migration when using non-default configurations

Tags: ios, swift, realm

In the realm docs I see the code example for migrations

```
let config = Realm.Configuration(
  // Set the new schema version. This must be greater than the previously used
  // version (if you've never set a schema version before, the version is 0).
  schemaVersion: 1,

  // Set the block which will be called automatically when opening a Realm with
  // a schema version lower than the one set above
  migrationBlock: { migration, oldSchemaVersion in
    // We haven’t migrated anything yet, so oldSchemaVersion == 0
    if (oldSchemaVersion < 1) {
      // Nothing to do!
      // Realm will automatically detect new properties and removed properties
      // And will update the schema on disk automatically
    }
  })

// Tell Realm to use this new configuration object for the default Realm
Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = config
```

and then it says to use `let realm = try! Realm()` to get the realm instance. However, in our application we are using our own realm configurations with something like

`let realm = try! Realm(configuration: RealmConfig.getConfig(typeURL: .userData)!)`

We have a few different configurations besides `.userData`. My question is, how does one go about doing migrations with these non-default configurations? The code example really only shows how to set the default configuration which is insignificant for my use. I couldn't find anything like

`Realm.Configuration.userData = config`

Does something like this exist that I am missing? Or is there another way I'm supposed to go about this?

Answer (score 1):

You can instantiate different Realm instances with different configurations like this:

```
let userDataConfiguration = Realm.Configuration(...)
let userDataRealm = try! Realm(configuration: userDataConfiguration)
```

Learn more in docs at https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#realms